# what is difference between fixed and delimited data store file format in oracle data integrator

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I am new in ODI
kindly guide me in that

what is difference between fixed and delimited data store file format in oracle data integrator

Answer (score 5):

Fixed format means that the fields in your file have a fixed length. For instance first column is always 10 characters, second is 3 characters and third is 20 characters.

Delimited format means that there is a character used to separate every column on each line. The most common format are CSV (Comma-separated values) or TSV (Tab-separated values) files.

So depending of how your data is structured in your source file, you need to choose fixed or delimited.